# How to prove this limit does not exist?

Tags: limits

I have the following limit:

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}  \frac{\sin(xy)}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + |y|} \times \|(x,y)\|}$$

Where I'm using the usual euclidean norm. I've been trying to find a curve that approximates (0,0) in a way such that the limit is not 0, but I'm really struggling to do so.

Comment: Did you mean $\sin(xy)$ instead of $\sin(x,y)$?

Comment: Yes, I did. Thanks, editing

Comment: I'm not seeing the sequence point

Comment: Are you sure this particular limit doesn't exist?

Comment: I was told it didn't, but the person who told me this could be wrong. The full exercise is finding for which natural n a certain function is differentiable. For all n but 1, I can prove this by definition. I was told the function shouldn't be differentiable for n=1. This is the limit when n=1

Comment: I am 100% sure this limit exists and converges to $0$. You probably made a mistake in the hidden part you didn't post.

Comment: @FranciscoJoséLetterio  Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}  \frac{\sin(xy)}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + |y|} \times ||(x,y)||}=\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{\sin(xy)}{xy} \frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + |y|} \times ||(x,y)||}$$

and

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}  \frac{\sin(xy)}{xy}=1$$

and by polar coordinates

$$\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + |y|} \times ||(x,y)||}=\frac{r\cos \theta \sin \theta}{\sqrt{r^2+r|\sin \theta|}}\to 0$$

indeed

$$0\le \frac{r|\cos \theta| |\sin \theta|}{\sqrt{r^2+r|\sin \theta|}}\le \frac{r|\cos \theta| |\sin \theta|}{\sqrt{r|\sin \theta|}} \frac{\sqrt{r|\sin \theta|}}{\sqrt{r|\sin \theta|}}=|\cos \theta|\sqrt{r|\sin \theta}| \to 0$$

Comment: Isn't the denominator r^2?

Comment: the norm of (x,y) is equal to r and cancels out with an r factor in the numerator

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but I got that the limit does exist.

Multiply the equation with $(xy)/(xy)$ to simplify the limit to (using $\sin(xy)\approx xy$ if $xy$ close to $0$)
$$ \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}  \frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + |y|} \cdot ||(x,y)||} $$
Write out 
$$ \sqrt{x^2+y^2+|y|}\cdot ||(x,y)|| = \sqrt{(x^2+y^2+|y|)(x^2+y^2)} = \sqrt{x^4 + 2x^2y^2  + y^4 + x^2|y| + y^2|y|} $$
If you divide this by $xy = \pm\sqrt{x^2y^2}$ (so, we are turning it around), you get
$$ \pm\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{y^2} + 2  + \frac{y^2}{x^2} + \frac{1}{|y|} + \frac{|y|}{x^2}} $$
If you let $x$ and $y$ tend to $0$, this will always tend to $\pm\infty$ by the $+1/|y|$ term. Hence, if you revert the fraction it converges to $\pm0=0$. Thus the limit does exist and it should be $0$.

Comment: You can't approximate this limit from the y=0 line

Comment: Nor from the x=0 axis either

Comment: @FranciscoJoséLetterio It's zero in both those cases as well though right?

Comment: if you fill in $x=0$ or $y=0$ the term in the numerator becomes $0$ and the denominator is non-zero such that the limit will be $0$ if you walk along the $x$ or $y$ axis.

Comment: Shouldn't we be able to prove the limit by definition then?

Comment: I don't see why there is a big problem, because my proof suggests that the limit does exist :)

Answer (score 0):

Using $|\sin(xy)|\le|xy|$  and then switching to polar coordinates, we have, for the square of the function,

$$\begin{align}
{\sin^2(xy)\over(x^2+y^2+|y|)(x^2+y^2)}
&\le{x^2y^2\over(x^2+y^2+|y|)(x^2+y^2)}\\
&={r\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta\over r+|\sin\theta|}\\
&\le{r\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta\over\max(r,|\sin\theta|)}\\
&=\min(\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta,r|\sin\theta|\cos^2\theta)\\
&\le r|\sin\theta|\cos^2\theta\\
&\le r
\end{align}$$

The squeeze theorem now tells us the limit of the original function is $0$, since its square tends to $0$ as $r\to0$.

Comment: Where did $sin^2 $ come from?

Comment: @FranciscoJoséLetterio, if you are asking about the $\sin^2(xy)$ at the very beginning, it's the square of your expression's numerator.